# How to run "gsettings" command inside a kickstart file?

Tags: gsettings, kickstart

I want to create an unattended installation cd of Ubuntu 12.04 with several customizations. I've written a kickstart file to do so, and it works perfectly. (I know that preseed technology exists, but incomprehensibly it fails whenever kickstart works like a charm).

However, when I want to execute (in %post section) the "gsettings" command to customize my desktop, anything happens. I've read in forums that "gsettings" only works when there's a Gnome session initiated (Unity is only one incarnation), but this it's a mess: I only want to have a kickstart file to configure parameters of Gnome in a very fast way.

Is there a manner of achieve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/99_my_custom_settings.gschema.override` with a content like

```
[org.gnome.Empathy.conversation]
theme="adium"
theme-variant="Normal"
adium-path="/usr/share/adium/message-styles/ubuntu.AdiumMessageStyle"

[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
gtk-theme="Ambiance"
icon-theme="ubuntu-mono-dark"
cursor-theme="DMZ-White"
font-name="Ubuntu 11"
monospace-font-name="Ubuntu Mono 13"
```

for whatever settings you want to change. Then run

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

to merge your changes with the GSettings data base.